# Changing order status value automatically Based on ordering Date

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am building an E-Commerce Application with Asp.net core MVC.

Order Model is build and when a user add an order it is created and saved in the DB.

But I want to add the following  functionality that when a user places an order, the status is set to **pending**, and then after 2 days from placing the order, it changes to **shipped**, and after 4 days from placing the order it changes to be **Delivered** and then removed from the DB.

how can I implement this kind of action ?

Comment: You could have a stored procedure in your DB that runs every day, and based on the order date, changes the state of the orders. This SP can be triggered by a service that runs on your webserver or app server[if you have 3-tier architecture].

Comment: In the real world these events should be updated as an when they happen and not on fixed duration.

Answer (score 0):

`You can use the "quartz job scheduler library". 
// Add Quartz services 
builder.Services.AddHostedService();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IJobFactory, SingletonJobFactory>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerFactory, StdSchedulerFactory>();
// Add our job
builder.Services.AddSingleton();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(new JobSchedule(
jobType: typeof(RemindersJob),
cronExpression: "0 0/5 * * * ?")); // run every 5 min
builder.Services.AddSingleton();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(new JobSchedule(
jobType: typeof(EmailJob),
cronExpression: "0 0/1 * * * ?"));

[https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/aspnet-core-integration.html`](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/aspnet-core-integration.html%60)